# basic text website for web design class need pointers

Tags: html, css

I am taking a web design class and the assignment is to ,make a basic text site with the following requirements link to external page
image embedded from a website.

`bold`

`italics`

`carriage return`

`list`

`font color change`

`font face change`

`comments`

`title`

`Heading <h1> <h2> etc...`
Before I turn it in I was wondering if the code is clean enough and where would rate it on a scale of 0 to 100?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>DJ Khaled key to success</title>
</head>
<!---https://twitter.com/djkhaled/status/649808000987865088-->
 <style>
  body {
background-image: url("http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/168223-   image/First-HTC-One-M9-wallpaper.jpg");
background-color: #cccccc;
background-size: 1400px 675px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

 }
  </style>
    <body>
    <font color="#0099ff"face="arial" size="7"><i>The key to more success is coco butter!</i></font></br>

  <a href="http://www.theydontwantyouto.win/"><img src="https://usatftw.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/khaled1.gif?w=1000http://i.imgur.com/qsoXB3G.gif> width="300" height="230"></a>
<br><b>click the gif above for the key to success</B><br>
   <h1>The keys to success -by DJ Khaled</h1>
 <ol>
<li><b>The key is to make it.</b></li>

 <li><b>Another one.</b></li>

 <li><b>Key to more success is clean heart and clean face.</b></li>

 <li><b>Smh they get mad when u have joy.</b></li>

  <li><b>There will be roadblocks but we will overcome them.</b></li>

 <li><b>You smart! You loyal! You're a genius!</b></li>

 <li><b>Those that weather the storm are the great ones.</B></li>

 <li><b>I changed a lot</b></li>

 <li><b>They don't want you to jet ski.</b></li>

 <li><b>I can deal with everything. I got the answer for anything.</B></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I never knew SO would rate code.. :) Better on Code Review..

Comment: Not really appropriate for this site, which is for getting help when you get stuck. That said... You open with `<b>` but close with `</B>` . Be consistent. A tip is to write open/close tags together first & then put content between them. Good code editors or shortcut tools will do this for you. Also, indent code properly - tags at the same level should have the same indentation. E.g. `<body>` is inside `<html>` & should be indented, Indent `<li>` items 1-level inside `<ol>` but at the same level as each other. Inline `style` is not ideal, but ok for 1st project. Last: you *should* jet ski!

Answer (score 3):

I want to point out some changes you can make that can improve your design and help with maintenance in the long run.

- **Indent** your code appropriately. Most IDE/editors already do these for you.

**Why do this?**
 - Easier to read and manage.

- Use `external` cascading stylesheets instead of `style tags` or `inline` styles.

**Why do this?**

- You keep your html files small and not bloated.
- It is easy to maintain, you only have to go to that file as oppose to having to scroll and use find and replace features, if your html gets any bigger you'll be pulling your hair out especially if you have heavy nesting.
- It is also a way to separate your **presentation** logic from your
  **markup**.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the page is grammatically wrong. It should be:

`<title>DJ Khaled's key to success</title>`

Here is a JSFIddle with the changes: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjjou3ks/)

I have removed the css and put it in a seperate stylesheet.

I have changed the `<B>` tags to `<b>` tags. And also, your src tag had errors,and I have changed that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<b>` and `<i>` you should consider `<strong>` and `<em>` (they give the highlighted text some meaning, other than a bold and italicized section). Also the `<font>` tag is now deprecated and should not be used (if it's class requirement, you should comment that to your tutor).

Your `<style>` tag is outside of the `<head>`

And also some of your tags are using uppercase text while others are lowercase.